# Как сделать боковые линии от текста в css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как  лучше сделать вот такие линии [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

причем вначале линия более жирная.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
body{
  background-color:#5c5c5c;
}
.line{
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
.bold_line{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0 50px;
  border-bottom:3px solid #fff;
  margin-bottom:-2px;
}
.text{
  font-size:24px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 5px 5px;
  margin-bottom: -12px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:#5c5c5c;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="bold_line">
    <div class="text">OUR SERVICES</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Эмуляция вашего браузера конечно-же. А о том, что - `У меня во всех браузерах немножко по-другому мой код отображается.`, Немножко не понятно, о чем сейчас речь.

Answer (score 4):

```css
html, body { height: 100%, margin: 0; padding: 0; }

div {
  display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  font: 300 1.6rem sans-serif; color: #f6f6f6;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #373737;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1 0 auto; align-self: flex-end;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 0 0.3em 0.25em 0.3em;
  background: 100% center / 1.8em 2.75px no-repeat linear-gradient(to right, #f6f6f6 0%, #f6f6f6 100%),
              100% center / 1px 1px repeat-x linear-gradient(to right, #f6f6f6 0%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #37373740;
}

div::after { background-position: 0% center; }
```

```html
<div>Our services</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: white;
}

div {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
}

div::before,
div::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: inherit;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-end;
  line-height: 0.8;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateY(25%);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

span::before {
  margin-right: 0.4rem;
}

span::after {
  margin-left: 0.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div><span>OUR SERVICES</span></div>
```