# Создайть нижнюю границу меньшего размера, чем элемент, и с более толстой серединой

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

Я использую стилизованные HR для создания разделителей секций.
Но теперь я пытаюсь создать элемент `H1` с нижней границей меньше ширины `H1` (переменная ширина в соответствии с шириной текста H1) и с более толстой чертой в середине (высотой).

Что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я просмотрел несколько поисковых источников, пытаясь найти решение, но не нашел ничего похожего.

Я пытался использовать: after и: before, но все равно застрял. Есть идеи?

Вот что я пробовал до сих пор:

```css
h1 {
  display:inline;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

h1:after {
 content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-bottom:3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>
My Text
</h1>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Create border-bottom smaller than element and with thicker middle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50051607/7394871) от участника  [@Russel Riehle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6739925/russel-riehle).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50051607/7394871

Comment: Похожая задача (тут линия ступенчатой толщины нужна под текстом, а там - по бокам от него): [Как сделать боковые линии от текста в css?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1063103/288409).

Comment: @yar85 таких вопросов, ответов с линиями под, около текста много и у нас и на Enso/ Это решение показалось мне интересным и полезным, поэтому и перевёл

Comment: @yar85 вы можете, при желании, дать свой вариант решения этого вопроса. Галочка и плюс гарантирован при качественном ответе

Comment: Вариант решения в уже написанном ответе, по сути использует тот же подход что в связанном вопросе, и тут вряд ли получится придумать что-то новое :) Использование линейного градиента в фоновой картинке - это хорошее, и самое оптимальное (имхо) решение из тех что возможны без помощи SVG (в которой я не очень разбираюсь, но она вроде позволяет сделать ступенчатую векторную линию которая будет растягиваться только "хвостиком": что-то вроде [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35526545/12506088), но с линией).

Comment: @yar85 добавил метки, чтобы стали возможны другие решения. На мой взгляд, чем больше решений, тем лучше

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а где метка `canvas`?))) Так не интересно.

Comment: @Leonid добавил метку, жду ответа :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя назвать данный ответ правильным, но попытка использовать `canvas` для этой задачи. Заметьте, что свойства `h1` меняются только на время вычисления истинной ширины текста, затем возвращается все на место. `H1` сохраняет свойство `display:block`, а также текст расположен по центру. При этом подчеркивание только на ширину самого текста.

Для того, чтобы поведение canvas было "естественным", добавляю свойство `display:inline`. Так он будет отцентрирован как и остальной текст, но требуется искусственный перенос на следующую строку. И эту проблему я смог решить только с помощью добавления тега `<br>`. И вот никак не могу уменьшить его высоту чтобы подчеркивание прижалось к тексту.

```js
const LINE_COLOR = '#ea596e';

let h1 = document.querySelector('h1');

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = 0;
canvas.height = 0;

let display = window.getComputedStyle(h1).getPropertyValue("display");
let align = window.getComputedStyle(h1).getPropertyValue("text-align");

h1.style.textAlign = 'left';
h1.style.display = 'inline-block';

let rect = h1.getBoundingClientRect();

h1.style.textAlign = align;
h1.style.display = display;

let w = canvas.width = rect.width;
let h = canvas.height = 5;

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = LINE_COLOR;
ctx.fillRect(20,2,w-40,1);
ctx.fillRect(w/4,0,w/2,h);
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">What an awsome solution!
    <br>
    <canvas style="display:inline"></canvas>
</h1>
```

Добавляю и "улучшенный" вариант с текстом, заключенным в `span`. Вместо `br` использую `div` с отрицательным `margin-top`. Теперь не надо играть свойствами `h1` чтобы получить ширину текста. Код проще.

Свойство `display:inline` для `canvas`, похоже смысла не имело, убираю лишнее.

```js
const LINE_COLOR = '#ea596e';

let h1_span = document.querySelector('h1 > span');

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

let w = canvas.width = h1_span.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let h = canvas.height = 5;

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = LINE_COLOR;
ctx.fillRect(w/8,2,w-w/4,1);
ctx.fillRect(w/4,0,w/2,h);
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center">
    <span>What an awsome solution!</span>
    <div style="margin-top: -16px"></div>
    <canvas></canvas>
</h1>
```

Comment: на коротких фразах работает чудесно. Проблемы с переносом действительно появляются на длинных фразах в заголовке

Comment: Тогда подчеркивание растягивается на всю ширину, а как должно быть иначе? При уменьшении экрана ничего не пересчитывается. Я тоже мог загнать текс в span и сильно упростить код)) Пропусти фразу "меньше ширины" немного изменил код.

Comment: в вопросе присутствует некоторая неопределенность. Непонятно насколько должно быть меньше подчеркивание длины фразы заголовка, насколько должна быть меньше толстая, короткая линия по сравнению с общей длиной. Поэтому, что имеем, то имеем.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, настаиваю на переопределении принятого ответа. У меня то глупость на тему. Кто же знал, что будет столько интересных ответов))

Comment: твой ответ был первым и вполне качественным. Плюс у меня принцип, если я принял решение, то потом не меняю его.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете легко сделать это с помощью linear-gradient без дополнительной разметки или псевдоэлемента:

```css
h1 {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:3em;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) 50% calc(100% - 2px)/80% 2px,
   linear-gradient(red 0 0) 50% 100%            /40% 6px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50051747/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Проблему с центрированием можно решить, поместив текст в `span`: https://jsfiddle.net/s38cmp9u/

Comment: Саша, ты отметил решением вариант с канвас который вообще не нужен для такой мелочи .....

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с псевдоэлементами

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h1::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 2px; left: 50%;
  width: calc(100% - 2rem);
  height: 1px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h1::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Text</h1>
<br>
<h1>My Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</h1>
```

Comment: интересный ответ. Я всегда говорил, - что **ты мастер CSS!** Помнишь, ещё со времен твоего ответа, [Как нарисовать автомобиль с помощью команд SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/849250/28748) Прошло ровно 3 года, а я хорошо помню твой ответ.

Answer (score 3):

С использованием SVG (насколько хватает моих скудных познаний в данной технологии):

```css
h1 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  font: bold 3rem sans-serif;
}

.test {
  display: block;
  width: 50%; height: 3px;
  margin: 0.1em auto 0;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.test .line { stroke: red; fill: red; transition: inherit; }

#grow:checked ~ h1 .test { width: 100%; }
#proportions:checked ~ h1 .test .line.thick { transform: scaleX(0.25); }
#thickness:checked ~ h1 .test { height: 6px; }
```

```html
<input id="grow" type="checkbox"><label for="grow">Увеличить ширину</label><br>
<input id="proportions" type="checkbox"><label for="proportions">Изменить пропорции сегментов</label><br>
<input id="thickness" type="checkbox"><label for="thickness">Повысить толщину</label><br>

<h1>Lorem Ipsum
  <svg class="test" viewBox="0 0 100 3" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <line class="line thin" x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100" y2="50%" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" />
    <rect class="line thick" width="100%" height="100%" transform="scale(0.5 1)" transform-origin="center" />
  </svg>
</h1>
```

Больше всего трудностей - с центровкой элемента `rect`'а (толстая часть линии) при сохранении возможности изменять его ширину.
При том что `transform` в SVG не работает с процентами (что похоже исключает динамическую центровку, а значит и задание ширины в абс. единицах таких как `px`), получилось сделать изменение размера толстого сегмента только относительно, через `scale`: т.е. в диапазоне `0..1`, где `1` это полная ширина всей линии.

Comment: `width: fit-content;` - экспериментальная штука из CSS4 (только эвергрин браузеры, глобал покрытие 91.14% без префиксов)... минздрав предупреждает, IE плачет, и т.д..

Comment: очень интересный и познавательный ответ, по крайней мере для меня. Из серии... А разве так можно было :)))  тут и сочетание модели objectBoundingBox и `viewBox="0 0 100 3" preserveAspectRatio="none"` то есть растягивание без соблюдения пропорций и scaleX -css Просто гремучий замес. Великолепно, буду изучать, экспериментировать. Появилось много свежих мыслей. Я бы ответил намного стандартней и скучнее :))) Вот она свежая кровь, обязательно отвечайте и дальше на вопросы SVG/ Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, честно признаюсь, сначала я делал с соблюдением пропорций (пытаясь использовать отличные от none значения `preserveAspectRatio` на вложенных `<svg>` с применением `use` атрибута и разных вьюбоксов) - но ничего не получалось, и окончательно психанув (типа "ох уж этот глупый SVG, надоел"), все стер и сделал наиболее примитивным способом :D технология-то мощная, но какая-то она недружественная к новичкам. Враждебная даже)) Еще смущает отсутствие инструментов отладки SVG в devtools браузера, аналогичных тем что мы имеем для HTML+CSS... если в будущем добавят, учиться будет проще.

Comment: очень много моих друзей программистов (довольно сильных и высокооплачиваемых) сломались на SVG :) поэкспериментировав неделю, две методом тыка, заканчивали одинаково - да пошёл этот SVG.  Хотя  в этом языке всё логично и математически точно. Его беда в том, что его никто не поддерживает настоящим образом, 25 лет ничего не делается Как начал его топить мелкософт продвигая свой платный VML, так и сейчас продолжается, но уже по другому.  И несмотря на это не могут выбросить SVG на свалку. Он до сих пор мощнее и гибче CSS, Canvas в анимации, фильтрах и т.д

Answer (score 2):

Решение с помощью псевдоэлемента и background-image:

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-image: url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCgAFAJEAAP8AAP///wAAAAAAACH5BAkAAAEALAAAAAAKAAUAAAgYAAMIBEAQgMCDAQoaHKiw4UGFCBkSPBgQAA==");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 5px;
  height: 5px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Very small!</h1><br>
<h1>This is small header!</h1><br>
<h1>This very very very long header!</h1>
```

Проблемы все те же + изображение настраивать.
Отступы можно задавать при помощи margin-left, margin-right.

Comment: может добавите в заголовок вместо `Для разнообразия:` --- Решение с помощью псевдоэлемента и `background-image`